# What's the difference between guice bind to instance and asEagersingleton

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

When we do a

`bind(ClassName).toInstance(new ClassName())`
 inside the configure method do we essentially mean that it is an "eagerly initialized singleton" by default?

If yes, what is the use of adding

`bind(ClassName).toInstance(new ClassName()).asEagerSingleton()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's not possible to append `.asEagerSingleton()`

The [complete signature of `toInstance`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/LinkedBindingBuilder.html#toInstance-T-) is the following:

```
void toInstance(T instance)
```

Since `toInstance(T)` returns nothing, you can't chain it with `.asEagerSingleton()`. The compilation will fail if you do that.

As you suspected, `toInstance` is already an eagerly-loaded singleton, this is why it's a chain-ending method (`void`) and not a binding declaration that can be further scoped.