# Guice bind, toInstance not injecting at startup (eager?) and instead doing during first call (lazy?)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, lazy-evaluation

According to this previously answered question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483440/whats-the-difference-between-guice-bind-to-instance-and-aseagersingleton/69097509#69097509)), `toInstance` is already an eagerly-loaded singleton but I had an injection of a table dependency which involves the cache update and it is happening only during the first call instead of at service startup. Could someone please tell what I am missing here and how to update the guice injection to make the cache update during startup instead of during the first call?

Comment: Why don't you use `bind(Something.class).to(SomethingImplclass).asEagerSingleton()` ?

Comment: I thought what you mentioned was related when I have an interface which is not the case, could you please tell if I am missing something?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Could you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve? and `asEagerSingleton()` can be used for concrete bindings too. e.g: `bind(String.class).asEagerSingleton();`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Use the PRODUCTION stage to eagerly inject singletons.

[Guice's wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) says:

> Eager singletons reveal initialization problems sooner, and ensure end-users get a consistent, snappy experience. Lazy singletons enable a faster edit-compile-run development cycle. Use the `Stage` enum to specify which strategy should be used.
>
> |  | PRODUCTION | DEVELOPMENT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | .asEagerSingleton() | eager | eager |
> | .in(Singleton.class) | eager | lazy |
> | .in(Scopes.SINGLETON) | eager | lazy |
> | @Singleton | *eager | lazy |
>
> `*` Guice will only eagerly build singletons for the types it knows about. These are the types mentioned in your modules, plus the transitive dependencies of those types.

So when you create your injector, you should decide whether you want a development stage or a production one. The injection of existing singletons happen at the same time as described above.

To do that, create the `Injector` like this:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, modules);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. I had some other bindings which I am not sure requires eager, could you please tell how to add specific bindings alone as eager and leave the rest as default values?

Comment: I think the issue might be that there was a chain of guice injections and I had not done it from the top till the end, so I tried that but still facing issues, have asked a separate question for that - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109496/bindclassname-class-aseagersingleton-is-lazy-and-not-eager), would be a great help if you could have a look at it.